# Java run+repaint = grey window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I'm trying to play around with JFrame/JPanels `repaint();` and so forth, but when I start a thread, and call repaint via run while true, it only spits out a line of `System.out.println("as");` which I put in place to check if loop was running.

So the question is:
Why is my drawings disappearing when calling repaint in a loop?
(It seems only a `JFrame` with the `canvas_width`/`height` is showing up, no panels etc.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    frame.getContentPane().add(p);
    Something s = new Something();

    p.add(s);
    p.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.pack();

}
```

And the something class:

```
public class Something extends JPanel implements Runnable {


public Something(){
    Thread t = new Thread();
    t.start();
    run();

}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-150, getHeight()-100);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(10, 10, 25, 25);

}


@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
    repaint();
    System.out.println("as");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }
}
}
```

Any help regarding the `contentpane` is appreciated, since, I'm not sure this is done correctly.

Comment: I guess the really important questions is, why?  What are you hoping to achieve?  From what I can see, you would get better performance (and support) from a `javax.swing.Timer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` in your `Thread`, implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks.  That ensures that `repaint()` is called on the Event Dispatch Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Also, repainting every 1 millisecond is being very optimistic.

Working SSCCE E.G.  (Note this version actually changes the co-ords of the resulting paint operations, just so we know something is happening!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Something extends JPanel {

    static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 100;
    private int xDelta = 0;

public Something(){
    ActionListener animater = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            repaint();
        }
    };
    Timer t = new Timer(10,animater);
    t.start();
}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-(xDelta--), getHeight()-100);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(xDelta, 10, 25, 25);

    if (xDelta<0) {
        xDelta = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    }
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    frame.getContentPane().add(p);
    Something s = new Something();

    p.add(s);
    p.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Just wondering, if anyone cares to explain, all the beginner examples I've seen, is doing Thread.start() & Run(), and if I'm gonna aim towards some game design, is this the wrong way?

Comment: *"all the beginner examples I've seen"* Speaking of which, where are you getting these examples?

Comment: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8b_Game_2DGraphics.html
Been looking through some templates, to see if I could understand and copy the logic. But so far not even been able to make the gameLoop & repaint work without everything being grey. But the idea of swing.timer worked.

Comment: That code does not `implements Runnable` as yours does.  It was that aspect of the code which made me wonder "Where the heck are all these crap examples coming from?".  So where *did* you get that idea?  But to answer your question:- **Yes it is the wrong way.**

Comment: Which is the wrong ? The run/Implements runnable one, or the swing.timer? 
Every time I've looked up gameloop or repaint + loop, or something like "Java Game Template", the implements runnable is the one used.

Comment: *"is the one used."*   Back in the days of using AWT components that might have made sense.  The trouble is that there is a lot of old AWT code out there, and some programmers mistakenly carried that approach over to Swing. *"Which is the wrong ?"* 1) *"The run/Implements runnable one"*  **Wrong!**  2) *"or the swing.timer"*  **Right!**  As you might observe, both the other answers were also wrong, though one went on to mention the Swing `Timer` as 'good practice'.  Not good enough to deserve an up-vote, but not as bad as the other answer.

Comment: Well, someone should 'cleanse' the web of bad practice, and have helped me a looong time ago.

Comment: *"someone should 'cleanse' the web of bad practice"*  Speaking of which, see [Why should CS teachers stop teaching applets?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196499/why-should-cs-teachers-stop-teaching-applets)  I am doing ***my*** part.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Starting a Runnable in a new Thread is done with [java.lang.Thread.Thread( Runnable )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) constructor.
2. Calling a method of a GUI component outside the Swing event loop is not a good practice, use a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead.

Your code becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
   new Timer( 40, new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         repaint
      }
   }).start();
   ...
}
```